# What arithmetic corresponds to minimal logic?

Tags: number-theory, logic, proof-theory

Starting from classical logic (Peano arithmetic, **PA**):

- Remove the law of excluded middle and we get intuitionistic logic (Heyting arithmetic, **HA**)
- Remove the principle of explosion and we get minimal logic (but what arithmetic?)

Comment: Note that the answer is **not** ["minimal arithmetic"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Minimal_Arithmetic), as much sense as that would make.

Answer (score 1):

This system lacks a standard, widely-accepted name. (How does one prove a negative? How about *the question asking for a standard name was left unanswered for 3+ years on a Q/A site frequented by experts*?) For now, let's call this system PAML (Peano Axioms in Minimal Logic).

Studying PAML is not fundamentally different from studying Heyting arithmetic, thanks to the following theorem:

> Let $\varphi$ be a formula of Heyting arithmetic (with negation $\neg P$ defined as $P \rightarrow \bot$). Let $\varphi^{0=1}$ denote the formula obtained by replacing each occurrence of $\bot$ in $\varphi$ with the formula $0 = 1$. Then PAML proves $\varphi^{0=1}$ precisely if Heyting arithmetic proves $\varphi$.

The proof of this statement simply translates HA-proofs into PAML-proofs, replacing every use of *ex falso quodlibet* $\bot \rightarrow A$ by a tailor-made proof of $0=1 \rightarrow A^{0=1}$. This is done by induction on the structure of $A$. We'll do the base case, as the inductive cases are straightforward.

If $A$ is atomic, then it either has the form $t_1 = t_2$ for terms $t_1,t_2$, or the form $\bot$. In the latter case we have to prove $0=1 \rightarrow 0=1$, which is easy. In the former case we have to prove $0=1 \rightarrow t_1 = t_2$. We can use the following argument. Assume $0=1$, multiply both sides by $t_1$ and use the usual facts about multiplication to obtain $0 = t_1$. Similarly, $0 = t_2$. Hence $t_1 = t_2$.

Comment: What if we use [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) instead?